# Single File component export - not using vuetify styling

Tags: vue-component, vuetify.js

I have a vuetify project (Windows / VSCODE).
Our plan is to create components for our **internal teams to use - no NPM**.
I created a hello-world.vue component and ran a script (below) from package.json to create a dist folder with that component.  This works fairly well, but in another application   demo.html or such the Vuetify Button v-btn does not have any of the styling from vuetify...    The script creates the individual components based off the vue file.
script executed to generate components "buildSFC": "cross-env  vue-cli-service build --target wc --name jcdc-sfc 'src/components/*.vue'"

**What am I missing to get VUETIFY styling and such?**

See GIT HUB for code:  https://github.com/wlafrance/jcdc-sfc
If you pull the git down, in a vue command line execute this script:  **npm run buildSFC**
Then look for a dist folder in the project and open the html file in chrome to see the issue.
So see what it is suppose to look like (the button)  **execute:  nmp run serve**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your publicPath in `vue.config.js` probably defaults to `/` which is you root drive. So if you have it running on Windows and on your C: drive then your `demo.html` will look in C:\ for the files.
Add a `publicPath: "./"` to your vue config.

Also check your package-json scripts. `buildLib` has a `./src/` but `buildSFC` does not.